# How to open a pdf with intent in Android Q

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I have written a code that open a file like pdf. For that I used intent like the below one:

```
public void openFile(Context context, File file) {
    String typeFile = "application/pdf";

    if (file.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), typeFile);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setType(typeFile);
        Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
        if (resInfo.size() > 0) {
            try {
                context.startActivity(openInChooser);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No application found which can open the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // PDF apps are not installed
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No application found which can open the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I run this code on Android 10 and 11, the Toast in else is executed but in older versions these codes work correctly.

So what should I do to open file in Android 10 and 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app should be crashing on Android 7.0+ with a `FileUriExposedException`. You need to get rid of `Uri.fromFile()` and [switch to `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Also, you can get rid of `queryIntentActivities()`. You do not need it, partly because there should always be a chooser, and partly because you have the `try`/`catch` block to catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` if there is no chooser for some strange reason. If your reason for `queryIntentActivities()` is to avoid an empty chooser, stop creating a chooser — the OS will add one automatically if one is appropriate. Alternatively, for Android 11+, you will need to deal with package visibility rules to be able to call `queryIntentActivities()`. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#open-a-file) for more.